# When Is a Windows Forms Data Source Destructed?

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

I have a class that implements `System::ComponentModel::INotifyPropertyChanged` and serves as a data source.  Call it `SourceThing`. Let's say it has a `String` property called `Data`.  It gets bound to a Windows Forms control like so:

```
SourceThing ^ mySourceThing = gcnew SourceThing();
myTextbox->DataBindings->Add("Text", mySourceThing, "Data");
```

The binding works as expected.  However, the `SourceThing` destructor is never called, even when the window containing the textbox is disposed (i.e. the window's destructor is called, but the `SourceThing` instance is never destroyed).  The only way I can cause the destructor to run on `SourceThing` is to use the `delete` operator on the handle.  I'd rather not have to retain handles to all the data sources when it seems like they should be destroyed automatically when the form is destroyed.

The application will create and dispose this particular form many times based on user actions, and having lots of `SourceThing` instances floating around is not ideal.  Why isn't the `SourceThing` destructor being called when the form is destroyed?

Comment: No, the Binding class is a pretty simple class and has no disposable members.  So Winforms doesn't have any reason nor mechanism to dispose it deterministically.  Since you added a destructor, it is up to you to get it called.

Comment: I see.  Further reading about CLR's garbage collection tells me that depending on Finalize behavior is a bad design.  Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about this but I guess the compiler creates a `Dispose()` method when defining a destructor in a C++ CLI class.

If this is the case, you should call `mySourceThing->Dispose()` when the form closes.

Hope it helps

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid having to do...  but thanks for the input.